# Cross-compilation issues with GCC/G++

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I am using gcc to compile a C++ application on my CI server (http://ci.berboe.co.uk) and as the vps that it is compiled on has the x86-64 architecture I need to cross-compile to get the compiled program to work on x86 computers.

I have installed gcc-multilib and g++-multilib and several other packages that were suggested in other places, but I still get an error when trying to compile. It is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Full logs are available here: http://ci.berboe.co.uk/job/MCServer%20Linux-x86/11/console

Any help towards resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Edit:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtbegin.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtend.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
```

I get this after having fixed the previous problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install 32 bits libs (`ia32-libs` in some distros, moving to this: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO in others, more on that if you ask for it).
- Be sure to add the i386 library path to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env. variable. (most certainly `export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/lib32:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and so one).
- Be sure to add the i386 include path to your `LD_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable.

Feel free to look for these libraries (once installed of course), using:

```
find / -iname "*libstdc++.so*" 2> /dev/null
```

for instance for the `libstdc++.so` library. `find` should report some path that you will be able to add to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I installed the package, but the compilation still does not work. I tried adding the LDLIBPATH to the .bashrc and then putting it right before and doing a manual make, and it still didn't work.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib32:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Comment: This is the error: `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++` And the command shows locations in /lib32 and /usr/lib32 so it should work.

Comment: The problem is, I have. The C++ args are: `-m32 -s -g -O3 -DNDEBUG`.

Comment: However, please see my edit I have another problem.

Comment: Hmm the `/usr/lib/gcc/i386-linux-gnu/.....` doesn't exist :(

Comment: I tried, but i think it said there was no such package... :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that *might* work:

1. Install `ia32-libs` package by running `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` . It is just a hunch, it might or it might not work.
2. Another solution can be to install a 32-bit linux on a virtual machine to compile the code.

This link might help:
 - http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6034.0

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off making an i386 chroot.  `mk-sbuild` (in ubuntu-dev-tools) and `schroot` make these very easy to manage.